# Centering form elements with left alignment

Tags: html, forms, text, center

I would like to center the elements in my form without moving the text or buttons from being aligned on the left.

So it would look like this:

[image]

The bottom square is supposed to be a button.

I want it centered, but the `<center>` tag moves the text and button so they're centered to the input box.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <div class="aside">
        <div id="center">
            Username:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username"><br>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="password" name="passwor"><br>
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Login"><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the css:

```
#center{
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

div.aside {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    line-height: 150%;
}

div.aside .button{
    padding:3px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    background-color: #00A1E6;
    border: 1px solid #0184BC;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: There's no such value "center" for "float" style. Valid values are: "left", "right", "none", "inherit". [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp).

Comment: I know, that was random crap I was experimenting with.  I shall remove it promptly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a parent div set to a max-width, and a child div with your content (left-aligned, smaller width) and use `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;` to center the child within the parent. However if you do this, you will need to set the width of your child div.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BSXvw/1/)

Comment: I don't want it centered in the middle of the page, I have a parent div already that I want to center the child to.
http://76.24.93.123/

I want the text and input fields to go to the center of the box on the left.

Comment: right now you have the "center" div set to be the same width as the "aside" div so margin left/right will not do anything. If you decrease the width of "center" it will center the content within the box. [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqBcZ/) Here I set the width of "center" to 150px.